# ServerConnection.Configuration does not exist

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm

I'm studying the CRM SDK.

When I trying the sample in msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328180%28v=crm.6%29.aspx

```
    public void Run(ServerConnection.Configuration serverConfig, bool promptforDelete)
```

I got the error:
The type name 'Configuration' does not exist in the type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have a class name mismatch. Your code is referencing `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection` for `ServerConnection.Configuration` in function, however it really should be [custom helper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309393.aspx) `ServerConnection` which is used throughout most of CRM samples.